# WINAPI: can't read from main disk (PhysicalDrive0)

Tags: c++, winapi, hard-drive

**Solved: See comments below. A multiple of 512 (or disk sector size) bytes should be read.**

I'm trying to read from my main drive (this drive is an SSD drive and the operating system is stored in this drive), but the function keeps failing and reading 0 bytes. I'm running this program as an administrator.

Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    char a[100];

    HANDLE hMainDisk = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hMainDisk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Main disk could not be found.\n"; //This is not printed.
    }

    unsigned char data[1000];
    BOOL succeeded = ReadFile(hMainDisk, bootloaderData, 1000, &numBytesRead, 0);
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    CloseHandle(hMainDisk);
    if (numBytesRead != 1000) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Less than 1,000 bytes were read. Only " << numBytesRead << " bytes were read\n"; //This is printed.
    }
    if (succeeded == FALSE) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Main disk read failed.\n"; //This is also printed
    }
    if (error == ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER || error ==     ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Too many IO requests.\n"; //This is not printed
    }

    std::cin >> a;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: And what is the result of GetLastError?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy 87

Comment: Unrelated, why march on into the abyss in this code if the createfile *failed*. You're error indicates an incorrect-parameter, btw, but by then it's too late. What's the error immediate after the createfile fails? (or does it even fail? you question says "the function keeps failing" but doesn't say which one).

Comment: this is because your file (disk file) have `FO_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING` flag. the buffer size - must be multiples of the volume sector size. 1000 is bad value

Comment: @WhozCraig The error code value after createfile is 0.

Comment: @RbMm Thank you. Changing the buffer size to 512 made the program work. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Then I concur with RbMm. Checking GetLastError making no sense after a successful API call notwithstanding, the restrictions for reading from a physical volume are pretty tight. You can (and should) [use an ioctl call to get the drive geometry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/100027/info-direct-drive-access-under-win32) to calculate the required buffer size. Guessing a value like 512 won't always work.

Comment: I think you may also need to align your buffer.

Comment: really you need get aligment information via `GetFileInformationByHandleEx(hMainDisk, FileAlignmentInfo, &fai, sizeof(fai))` or via `NtQueryInformationFile` with `FileAlignmentInformation` and sector size with say `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY` - align buffer and read multiple sector